# cuda vs2013 v120xp compile error

Tags: cuda, compiler-errors

I'm using VS2013(update 4) + CUDA 6.5 + win7-32bit

My CUDA program compiles fine without the **v120xp** option, I need it support winXP. But there're lots of compile error with **v120xp** specified.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Create a new project with VS2013's CUDA wizard
2. Change the `Platform Toolset` to `Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)`
3. Compile

The compile error looks like:

```
1>G:\vs2013\VC\include\yvals.h(666): error : expected a ";"
1>G:\vs2013\VC\include\yvals.h(667): error : expected a ";"
1>G:\vs2013\VC\include\exception(460): error : "explicit" is not allowed
1>  kernel.cu
```

I also compiled the program with CMake, everything is ok(with the v120_xp). Though I write code with CMake, my company uses VS2013, so I need to generate a VS2013 project for my colleagues.

How to make it compile? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, a workaround for this:

Don't change the Platform Toolset, leave it as **v120**, and add `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01` or `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01` manually in `Command Line` setting